# slick slider goto NN Slide after init

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I want to jump on NN Slide (Slick Slider) after load the page.

JS:

```
 var WineSlider = $('.carousel').slick({
    // infinite: true,
    slide: 'div',
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    speed: 750,
    centerMode: true,
    draggable:false,
});

WineSlider.on('init', function(event, slick) {
WineSlider.slick('slickGoTo', 10);
```

What is wrong? Thansk for help.

Comment: Do you have this inside a `document.ready`?

Comment: Yes, everything is inside a document.ready

Answer (score 2):

There is some JavaScript syntax error in your code:

```js
WineSlider.on('init', function(event, slick) {
  WineSlider.slick('slickGoTo', 10);
});
```

But this is actually not the problem. You don't need to run the init on this. You can just slide to the slide with index 10 like this:

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
    // infinite: true,
    slide: 'div',
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    speed: 750,
    centerMode: true,
    draggable: false,
});

$('.carousel').slick('slickGoTo', 10);
```